# Cartesian $-10i$ to Polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to convert the following problem to polar form:

$$z=-j10.$$

Using this equation, where $|z|=r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\arg z=\theta=\arctan(y/x).$

$$\eqalign{z&=|z|e^{j\arg z}\\ &=re^{j\theta}\\&=r\angle\theta.}$$

I determined that x = 0 and y = -10. However, if I plug `x` and `y` into `arctan(y/x)`, the result would be indetermined since we're dividing by 0. The solution to that problem is `10<-90degrees`.

Could someone give me some insight on how to convert the above cartesian to polar form?

Comment: Above all and before anything else, you should draw the picture.

Comment: If you draw the Argand diagram for this, the answer should be immediately apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

> http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number.html

The polar of a complex number is given by:
$$z = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$$
In your example:
$$z = -10i$$
$$r = \sqrt{0^2+(-10)^2} = 10$$
$$\theta = \arctan(\frac{-10}{0}) = \frac{3\pi}{2}$$
$\theta$ is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ because the complex number is in the III quadrant. So the polar form of our complex number is $$z = 10(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}) + i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}))$$

Comment: Thanks Vishwa! This answer really explained it in the way I understand.

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First find $\alpha$ that $\cos \alpha=0$, there are two values in $[0,2\pi)$:$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, for second you have $\sin \alpha=-1$ for first $\sin \alpha=1$, so: $-10i=10(\cos \frac{3\pi}{2} + i\sin\frac{3\pi}{2})$

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get the 3pi/2?

Comment: Hi agha. Thank you for your assistance. Would I simply use Euler's Formula to convert your form to the polar form I want?

Comment: Yes, but in this case it's easier, because $x=0$, so you can get solution immediately.